# Constructor arguments always end up being 0

Tags: java

I am trying an example program regarding inheritance (i am a beginner, i apologise for silly mistakes in my code). What I have observed is that the arguments I pass (in the constructor) when creating the objects, when they are fed in the variables, the variables somehow end up at a value of 0. the following is my code:

```
class Box
{
    double length, width, height, vol;

    Box(double l, double b, double h)
    {
        length = l; 
        width = b; 
        height = h;
    }

    Box(Box obj)
    {
        obj.length = length;
        obj.width = width;
        obj.height = height;
    }

    Box(double l)
    {
        length = width = height = l;
    }

    Box()
    {
        length = width = height = 0;
    }

    double volume()
    {
        vol = length * width * height;
        return vol;
    }
}

class WeightBox extends Box
{
    double weight;
    WeightBox(double l, double b, double h, double w)
    {
        super(l, b, h);
        weight = w;
    }

    WeightBox(double l, double w)
    {
        super(l);
        weight = w;
    }

    WeightBox(WeightBox obj)
    {
        super(obj);
        obj.weight = weight;
    }

    WeightBox()
    {
        super();
        weight = 0;
    }
}
public class boxInherit 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WeightBox box1 = new WeightBox(10, 20, 30, 40);
        WeightBox box2 = new WeightBox(10, 20);
        WeightBox box3 = new WeightBox(box1);
        int i = 1;
        WeightBox[] boxes = {box1, box2, box3};
        for(WeightBox ob : boxes)
        {
            System.out.println("Box no. " + i++ + " length = " + ob.length + " width = "+ ob.width + " height =" + ob.height +" volume = " + ob.volume() + " Weight = " + ob.weight );
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when the box1 object is initialized, it takes 4 arguments, which end up in the length, width, height and weight variables respectively. However when box1's variables are printed, it turns out they have a value of zero.

The box1 should call the respective overload of WeightBox, and then the first 3 values should pass onto the box class by super() function and the weight variable should be given the value of the 4th argument, but what ive noticed is that the length, width, height, volume and weight of box1 is 0, this also makes so that the values of box3, which is a clone of box1 also ends up with all values as 0, although they should be 10, 20, 30 and 40 respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Your copy constructor

```
Box(Box obj)
{
    obj.length = length;
    obj.width = width;
    obj.height = height;
}
```

does the wrong thing. It will change the `length`, `width` and `height` fields of the given object `obj` (which comes into the constructor) with the values of `this.length`, `this.width` and `this.height`, which are all `0`. You want to write it like this:

```
Box(Box obj)
{
    this.length = obj.length;
    this.width  = obj.width;
    this.height = obj.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting out, get used to using the debugger.  If you put a breakpoint on the first line and then step through the code (often F7/F8) you will find that your constructor assignments are the opposite of what you intended.  The following should work

```
        Box(Box obj)
        {
            this.length = obj.length;
            this.width = obj.width;
            this.height = obj.height;
        }
```